# Привязка контрола к родительскому свойству wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, usercontrol

Всем добрый день.
Есть дочерний контрол CardElement, который содержит картинку и другие элементы.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Client.Controls.CardElement"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Client.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="368" d:DesignWidth="252" x:Name="CardElementControl">
    <Grid x:Name="Back">
        <Image Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:TopControl}, Path=Image, IsAsync=True}"
               RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant"
               Height="368" 
               Width="252" Stretch="Fill"/>
    </Grid>
```

Есть другой родительский контрол, который использует контрол CardElement в стеке.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="ScreenshotList">
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding images, Mode=TwoWay}" Background="#FFFF1515" >
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <local:CardElement/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
```

Родительский контрол привязывается к своему viewmodel, в котором есть коллекция объектов.

```
 public ObservableCollection<Card> images { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Card>();

    public class Card : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string image;

        public string Image
        {
            get { return title; }
            set { title = value; OnPropertyChanged("Image"); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
```

Мне нужно привязать source дочернего контрола к свойству соответствующего элемента коллекции. Подскажите, как дочерний элемент привязать к свойству элемента из родительской коллекции?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, в чём ваша проблема. `DataContext` вашего `CardElement` — это экземпляр `Card`. А к чем вы хотите привязаться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как сказал VladD в комментариях - на ваш контрол `CardElement` уже привязан экземпляр класса `Card` к `DataContext` (благодаря этому `ItemsSource="{Binding images, Mode=TwoWay}"`). Поэтому вам остается только правильно биндить изображение внутри `CardElement`:

```
    <Image Source="{Binding Image}"
           RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant"
           Height="368" 
           Width="252" Stretch="Fill"/>
```

Так же можете специфицировать вашему контролу `CardElement` желаемый тип дата контекста (не обязательно, но желательно):

```
<UserControl x:Class="Client.Controls.CardElement"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Client.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="368" d:DesignWidth="252" x:Name="CardElementControl"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance NAMESPACE:Card}"
>
```

Дополняя ответ могу вам посоветовать соблюсти инкапсуляцию и все же убрать setter свойства коллекции картинок (C# 6.0!):

```
public ObservableCollection<Card> Images { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Card>();
```

Либо реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged` для этого свойства, если кто-то все же изменяет саму коллекцию.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался)